# How to separate n-sided polygons in Scratch

Tags: spacing, mit-scratch

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/123719143/#player

I have written a simple Scratch exercise for my son that draws an array of n-sided polygons, but I want the spacing to be consistent, regardless of the number of sides chosen. It's not bad as it is, though I feel that the line where I calculate the apothem is overcomplicated and ugly (the 0.35 was reached through experimentation):

set apothem to sides * 0.35 * length / cos of 180 / sides

where sides is the number of sides for the poly and length is the side length.

The equation line was lifted and modified from a different script, not originally written by me otherwise I'd better know how to parse it.

I'd appreciate a way to make it more elegant :)

B

Comment: I am not a geometry teacher, and I haven't even done much geometry myself, but you might find [this mathisfun.com page](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/regular-polygons.html) helpful..

Comment: Your link led me to this link: http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonradius.html which led me to setting Scratch like so:

set Radius to Length / 180 / 2 * sin of sides * 2500

the "* 2500" is still winging it, but this feels far more "elegant" already, thanks :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking but I would recommend setting a limit on your Scratch program because if you enter a large number for the dimensions, the program will draw very crooked shapes since the sprite cannot exit the display.